# CSS Transition does not work with DOM creation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, dom, transition

Now I'm trying to make the animation using CSS transition after created img tag dynamically by DOM.

Here I'll list the DEMO including 2 examples.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsh19xr0/13/).

```js
 function OneBaloon() {
    baloon1 = document.createElement('img');
    baloon1.id = 'slow_first_img';
    baloon1.setAttribute('src', 'http://s27.postimg.org/6xww0tj9f/baloon.gif');
 var slow_first = document.getElementById("slow_first");
 slow_first.appendChild(baloon1);
 baloon1.style.top = "-50px";
    baloon1.style.visibility = "visible";
    baloon1.style.opacity = 1;
};


function PopUp() {
    var sfd = document.getElementById("slow_first_div");
    sfd.style.top = "-50px";
    sfd.style.visibility = "visible";
    sfd.style.opacity = 1;
};
```

```css
div#main{
position: relative;
}

.button {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #248;
    color: #fff;
    border-style: none;
}

#slow_first_div{
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#slow_first_img{
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<body style="position:relative;">
 <div style="position:absolute;">
  <h2>DEMO</h2>
 </div>
 <div id="main" style="position:absolute;top:150px;">
  <ul style="padding-left:0px;">
      <li id="slow_first">
        <button onClick="OneBaloon()" class="button">DOM</button>
      </li>
            <div style="height:100px;"></div>
      <li>
        <button onClick="PopUp()" class="button">ORIGINAL</button>
        <img id="slow_first_div" src="http://s27.postimg.org/6xww0tj9f/baloon.gif"></img>
      </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

One is what I mentioned already(using DOM).

The other makes animation available by not using DOM(write img tag directly in the HTML)

And my question is why the former case doesn't work, but the latter one works completely.

Sadly, I can't distinguish any difference between them at all.

Plase I need your help!

Comment: There's no change to the position of the image created into DOM. Use [a timeout](https://jsfiddle.net/L2mfsg4u/) to create a change.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't want to use timeout since I wanna keep  the changing speed ('transition : all 0.5s ease-in-out'). Could you tell me why these two don't do the same action?

Comment: Use a smaller delay than I did, or set the position in an `image.onload` handler. The delay won't affect to the animation itself.

Comment: What I want to rectify is that the one using Timeout pops up completely first and then move the other one using transition seems getting appeared with movement though. No way to use transition for the former one?

Comment: Okay image.onload made transition worked! Thanks Teemu for your help. You're the best.

Comment: U can use setTimeout with 1ms. https://jsfiddle.net/Lsh19xr0/14/